# How to position the div inside another div?

Tags: css, html

I have this website and I need help. What I want is to have the light blue paragraph and the red paragraph together. I have tried everything and I was wondering how can I style them. I have tried to use float but it wont change anything.

When I try in my browser I have a border around the `main` id tag, but the red paragraph is out of that box and I don't know why? So I think I'm missing a `<div>` or a `</div>`.

### Code:

### http://jsfiddle.net/d4BKy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by together, you mean side by side, use the next code:

```
#backgroundInfo{
border-style:solid;
border-color:#7FFFD4;
border-width:2px;
width:49%;
float:left;
}

#mainContent{

width:49%;
border-style:solid;
border-color:red;
border-width:2px;
float:right;
}
```